# HTML Video tag not choosing correct source

Tags: html

I am using the `video` tag with two `source` tags inside it one with a webm video for non Safari browsers and one with mp4 for Safari, the problem is that the first `source` tag is being played regardless of which browser I am on... So for example if I am on Safari and in the code the WebM `source` tag is first that'll play and look really bad, and the opposite is true when on Chrome.

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MarwanAK10/pen/gOzydNJ)

And here's the code

```
<div class="container">
  <video id="div_block-207-1652" class="ct-div-block" playsinline muted autoplay loop>
        <source id="div_block-209-1652" class="ct-div-block" type="video/mp4" src="https://www.ledrabrands.com/alphabet-lighting/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2022/10/masked-bottom_1-hevc-safari.mp4">
    
        <source id="div_block-208-1652" class="ct-div-block" type="video/webm" src="https://www.ledrabrands.com/alphabet-lighting/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2022/10/masked-bottom_1-vp9-chrome.webm">
     
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Quentin Thank you, you're right. I added the code in the question but inline demo isn't showing up for some reason